# Как передать компонент для отрисовки родительскому компоненту Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, компоненты

Есть задача сделать модальные окна на сайте. В моём понимании, я должен положить компонент модального окна в App.vue, отлавливать событие, что кто то хочет его открыть и открывать. Но как передавать компоненты в это модальное окно?

### Компонент модального окна

```
    <template>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="modalWrapper" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
             /**
              * Здесь необходимо рендерить компонент который пришел аргументом 
              * в обработчик события openMainModal. 
              * Вроде того <someComponent><someComponent>
              */
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </template>

    <script>
      import {eventEmitter} from '../main'

      export default {
        name: "Modal",

        data() {
          return {
          }
        },
        methods: {
          _openModalHandler(someComponent) {
            $('#modalWrapper').modal('show');
          }
        },
        created() {
          eventEmitter.$on('openMainModal', this._openModalHandler);
        }
      }
    </script>

    <style scoped>

    </style>
```

## App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

    <nav class="navbar">...</nav>

    <div class="page-content-wrapper">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>

    // Компонент "Модальное окно"
    <modal></modal>

   </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Modal from './Controls/Modal'

  export default {
    components: {
      modal: Modal
    }
  }
</script>

<style lang="scss">

</style>
```

## Любой компонент, который может открывать модалки.

Например карточка товара. При клике на кнопку предосмотр, мне нужно открыть модальное окно и отрендерить в нем компонент предосмотра и быстрой покупки.

```
<template>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <img :src="'../../static/'+product.img" alt="">
        <h5 class="card-title product-title">{{product.title}}</h5>
          <a href="#" @click.prevent="openModal(product)" class="form-control btn btn-outline-info">
            <i class="far fa-eye"></i>
          </a>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {eventEmitter} from '../../main'
  /**
   * Хочется 
   * import {productPreviewer} from '../Controls/Product/Previewer'
   */
  export default {
    name: "ProductCard",
    props: ['product'],
    methods: {
      openModal(product) {
        eventEmitter.$emit('openMainModal', productPreviewer);
      },
    }
  }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

Иерархия

```
App.vue
 |
 +--Modal
 +--pages/Catalog
 +--Controls
     |
     +--Product
         |
         +--Card
         +--Previewer
```

Как такое реализовать? Или, если я вообще всё неправильно себе представляю, то как лучше сделать?

Comment: Если используете vuex можете использовать его для отслеживания изменений и наполнения контентом. А отслеживать через v-if. Если нет, как у вас сейчас, можно модальное окно генерировать в отдельных компонентах, где они вызываются.

Answer (score 1):

`Vuex`

```
const dialog = {
  state: {
    show: false,
    data: {},
    title: "",
    component: ''
  },
  mutations: {
    DIALOG_CLOSE(state) {
      state.show = false;
      state.title = "";
      state.component = "";
      state.data = {};
    },
    DIALOG_SHOW(state, payload) {
      const type = payload.type
      state.show = true;
      state.data = payload.data;
      state.title = payload.title;
      state.component = typeDialog[type]
    }
  },
  actions: {
    DIALOG_SHOW({commit}, payload){
      commit("DIALOG_CLOSE");
      commit("DIALOG_SHOW", payload);
    }
  }
};
```

`Dialog.vue`

```
<template>
  <section v-if="$store.state.dialog.show" >
    <div  :style="{height, width}">
      <div  v-if="title">
        <div >{{title}}</div>
        <Icon  name="circle-close" @click.native="closeDialogWindow"></Icon>
      </div>
      <components  @set-height="setHeight" :is="$store.state.dialog.component" :data="$store.state.dialog.data"></components>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import DialogContent from "./DialogContent";

export default {
  name: "DialogWindow",
  components: { ...DialogContent },
  data() {
    return {
      height: "90%",
      width: "90%"
    };
  },
  computed: {
    title(){
      return this.$store.state.dialog.title;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    closeDialogWindow() {
      this.$store.commit("DIALOG_CLOSE");
    },
    setHeight(e){
      this.height = e.height;
      this.width = e.width;
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

`/DialogContent/Message.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="message">
    <div class="message__content">{{data.txt}}</div>
    <div class="message__answer">
      <div class="ok" @click="closeDialogWindow">OK</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import glossary from "@/components/mixins/glossary.vue";

export default {
  name: "Message",
  props: {
    data: Object
  },
  created() {
    this.$emit("set-height", { width: "50%", height: "50%" });
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    closeDialogWindow() {
      this.$store.commit("DIALOG_CLOSE");
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

В нужный момент диспатчите открытие окна с нужными данными и модальное окно откроется